# Proving abslotuely convergence of a sequence by linear operator theory

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

This is my first question posted, I'm not sure whether the style and format are good, but any help would be appreciated.

I came into this problem when reading the book "Elementary functional analysis" and I am confused by the proof. The problem is:

Suppose $\{a_n\}^\infty_1 $ is a sequence of complex numbers such that $\sum_1^\infty a_n b_n $ converges whenever $\{b_n\}^\infty_1 $ is in Banach space $c_0=\{\{a_n\}_1^\infty: a_n$ converges to $0\}$ in supremum norm. Aim to prove that $\sum_1^\infty |a_n|<\infty$.

The proof first defines a sequence of operators $T_k:c_0\rightarrow{\mathbb C}$
$$T_k=\sum_{j=1}^k a_jb_j$$
and shows that $||T_k||=\sum_{j=1}^k |a_j|$ and for each $b=\{b_n\}\in c_0$, $lim_{k\to\infty}T_k(b)$ exists.

I can understand everything above, but then the book says, since $sup_k|T_k(b)|<\infty$ we have $sup_k\{||T_k||\}<\infty$ by uniform boundedness principle and thus$\sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_j|<\infty$.

My understanding is that since here we have pointwise limit of a sequence of bounded linear operators for all points in $c_0$, it would be helpful to apply Banach-Steinhaus Theorem to obtain that $\lim_{k\to\infty}T_k$ is a bounded linear operator. And for proof in the book, I fail to understand how $sup_k\{||T_k||:k\in{\mathbb N}\}$ equals $||\lim_{k\to\infty}T_k||$. Many thanks.

Comment: they're not the same, but a sequence with a limit is always bounded

Comment: $T_kb\to Tb,$ hence $\|T_kb\|\to\|Tb\|.$ Thus $\|Tb\|\le \sup_k\|T_kb\|\le \sup_k\|T_k\|\, \|b\|$ This gives $\|T\|\le \sup_k\|T_k\|$

Comment: Oh, I see, so it looks like both theorems can be used here.